Typeset good-looking -> arrow
I have a piece of software that includes the string "Data -> Memory" in a toolbar; that is, an arrow comprised of a dash and a greater than. I want to write about it in LaTeX. The dash is easy, but I can't figure out how to represent the > without LaTeX trying to make it pretty and mathematical, which makes it look much larger than the dash and thereby makes the arrow look ridiculous. > shows up as an upside-down question mark, \textgreater is a big mathematical greater than, $\text{>}$ is also an upside down question mark. Anyone have any ideas?
That is, how do I get simple ASCII plaintext ">" sign in the same font as the rest of my text?

just use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and > will print as > or use \texttt{Data -> Memory} as in monospace > prints as > even in OT1 encoding

You can also use \textgreater{}, or this answer has some 'fancy' options, if you don't like the two-character combination

TeX is aimed at good typesetting and -> is nothing that can be considered good typesetting.
In my opinion you should use an arrow, which -> is just an approximation of using ASCII, but nowadays we have full-fledged fonts that have arrows.
In any case, I recommend to define a command for the job: even if you end up with choosing \texttt{->}, using a command makes it easy to change your mind later, if you find a better representation.
Take your pick.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}

\newcommand{\ttoA}{\unskip~\texttt{->} }
\newcommand{\ttoB}{\unskip~\textrightarrow\ }
\newcommand{\ttoC}{\unskip~$\varrightarrow$ }
\newcommand{\ttoD}{\unskip~$-\!$\raisebox{0.175ex}{$\scriptstyle>$} }

\begin{document}

Data \ttoA Memory

Data \ttoB Memory

Data \ttoC Memory

Data \ttoD Memory

\end{document}



I wound up using \verb|->|. \texttt{->} also works well. According to this they're pretty similar in practice. I haven't compared to \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

They're actually very different in practice because \texttt{} will render any LaTeX commands you have included, whereas \verb|| will not.
